# Is there a non-heuristic way of finding the encoding of a string (ie. list)?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, erlang

For IoDevices one can use `io:getopts/1` for example but I couldn't find any method for plain strings.

For example,

```
ManPage = os:cmd("man ls").           
%   [76,83,40,49,41,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,
%   32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32|...]

io:format("~p~n",[ManPage]).         
%   [76,83,40,49,41,(...)

io:format("~ts~n",[ManPage]).
%   LS(1)                   User Commands         LS(1)
%   NAME
%          ls - list directory contents
```

The documentation [on using Unicode in Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html) mentions only heuristic ways but it may be out of date because according to the examples `io_lib:format/2` with `~ts` control characters produces utf-8 output. Trying it with Erlang 18.0:

```
Bullet = "\x{2022}".
%   [8226]

io:format("~ts~n", [Bullet]).
%   •
%   ok
io:format("~ts~n", ["•"]).   
%   •
%   ok

io_lib:format("~ts~n", [Bullet]).
%   [[8226],"\n"]
```

I know that I could use `unicode:characters_to_binary/{1,2,3}` because it accepts latin1 or utf8 encoded input and spits out unicode encoded output but I was curious if there is another way.

Interestingly, `unicode:characters_to_binary/1` works fine whereas `unicode:characters_to_list/1` does not (or I am misusing it).

```
unicode:characters_to_binary(ManPage).                       
%   <<"LS(1)   User Commands   LS(1)\n\n\n\nNAME\n  "...>>

unicode:characters_to_list(ManPage).  
%   [76,83,40|...]

unicode:characters_to_list(ManPage, latin1).
%   {error,"LS(1)   User Commands  LS(1",
     [8208,10,32|...]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only heuristic ways to determine character encoding, unfortunately. There is a brief explanation why [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file).

That said, in the particular case you specify above the real question is what encoding the system (not the Erlang) shell is set to. We can find that out by checking the environment directly (though this is going to be a somewhat platform-specific solution -- I'm writing this from a Debian-derived system that uses Bash):

```
1> LANG = os:cmd("echo $LANG").
"ja_JP.UTF-8\n"
2> {_, Enc} = lists:split(6, LANG).
{"ja_JP.","UTF-8\n"}
3> Encoding = string:strip(Enc, right, $\n).
"UTF-8"
```

This is, however, a rather crap solution. It is totally non-portable and there is no guarantee that your environment actually follows the rules and puts a 5-character language/region, then a dot, then the encoding into its `$LANG` environment variable. I'm pretty sure this doesn't work, for example, on at least some versions of Solaris, and on AIX I think the way to get at the encoding is by checking `$LC_CTYPE` or something similar (or maybe that's backwards... or... see, the fact that *I don't even remember the quirk to this* is indication enough that this is unreliable).

Another way is to use the `locale` command and have it give you the charset directly:

```
4> os:cmd("locale charmap").
"UTF-8\n"
```

That trailing newline is annoying to me, so...

```
5> string:strip(os:cmd("locale charmap"), right, $\n).
"UTF-8"
```

That said, the `locale` command also does not exist everywhere. In any case, some combination of checking for locale output data from the environment and the environment variables should do the trick, though to make it portable you will need arm your system with a few ways to do this. Fortunately *most* systems are utf8 by default now, with the exception of Windows, but at least Windows is *mostly* internally standardized.

(If you're dealing specifically with man pages... Keep in mind that man pages have control characters embedded in them for markup, so while the text-only output of a man page will be what you expect, the actual manpage data as interpreted by `man` is marked up. Depending on what you are doing it may be easier to manipulate the manpage archive data directly.)

Comment: I was just playing around with a local build of Yaws and the script on the documentation page called `man` directly. I figured that the encoding of the result would be set by the shell but I hoped for a "lazy" solution. Thanks for the detailed explanation on environment variables because so far I had only experience with other Linux distros and not unices.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear what programming language are we talking about, but there is no such method.

You may ask the user to set environment variables LC_ALL/LC_CTYPE/LANG to match the data, but cannot be sure they actually do that.

What's more, your program might have to process different encodings in the same program-run (e.g. coming from different files), so you either use some heuristic to guess the encoding (expect troubles!), or give the user a way to specify the encoding -- like text editors do when you open file.

Comment: The original question contained "in Erlang" but it got edited out. I hoped it had a silver bullet other languages didn't have that I did not know about (it was naive I know but I had to try).